# After loading a new route old instances of controller is still running

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-route

I have a route which is loading a page based on the parameters:

```
.when('/:num/:den', {
templateUrl : 'app/views/templates/home.html',
controller :"ProductContoller",
controllerAs: "product",
reloadOnSearch : false });
```

The problem is any time that I reload the route, there is a new instance of the controller along with all previous instances still running.
I have Socket.IO listeners in my controller to get some data from server in case of any update.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need to clean up your socket.io listeners? If you listen for the destroy event on scope, you can tidy up any listeners there :) It will look something like `$scope.$on('destroy', function( /* close your listener(s) here */ ) {});`

Comment: The problem is, there is no destroy event coming

Comment: How are your other controller instances running?

Comment: I just check them and they all stay running after changing the routes!

Comment: How do you check them?

Comment: Found the problem, first I was looking for destroy event! forgetting $, "$destroy". Also I had a bad mix up in my Socket service, in fact I was passing references of controllers to an object array in my Socket service.
Corrected that and now I get the $destroy event, and cleaning up socket listeners.
Thank you for your follow up.

Comment: If I create an answer with my original comment I made on this, any chance you'll mark it as the correct answer, since it was what you were after all along? :)

Comment: Oh, ignore that - you answered your own question! Thought someone external was stealing my fake internet points!

Comment: :D I didn't get what do you mean, but if I did something wrong or against rules here, I'm sorry ;)

Comment: No you didn't :) It's all good! Glad you solved your problem and wrote up a good quality answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of anybody else have the same problem, I was using Socket.IO, and it's listeners were still running so I added socket Emitter method, removeAllListeners, which is the same method as removeListener, removeListenerEvent and off. 
Now when I get "$destroy" event I am removing all those listeners by just passing no arguments to the method, or I can remove specific ones by stating the name of the events or even a specific handler by stating name of the event and name of the handler function.

Following is the code from Socke.IO source!

```
Emitter.prototype.off =
Emitter.prototype.removeListener =
Emitter.prototype.removeAllListeners =
Emitter.prototype.removeEventListener = function(event, fn)
```

and this is how I passed all the needed methods to my Service:

```
.factory('socketio', ["$rootScope", function ($rootScope) {
        var socket = io.connect();
        console.log(socket);
        return {
            on : function (eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });

            },
            removeAllListeners : function (eventName, callback) {
                socket.removeAllListeners(eventName, callback);
            },

            emit : function (eventName, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.apply(function () {
                        if (callback)
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });

            }

        };

    }
]);
```